# SSH config file setup for port forwarding AND SSH access to bastion

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have a publicly-accessible bastion host. I am presently able to SSH to the bastion with `ssh bastion` using this in my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host bastion
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    HostName bastion.foo.com
    User my-user
    Port 2222
    PubKeyAuthentication yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bastion.pem
    ServerAliveInterval 30
```

Now I have a Redis instance inside the firewall which I would like to forward a local port to. This works:

```
ssh -L 6000:redis.private.foo.com:6379 bastion
```

But I want a config Host shortcut so I can just type `ssh redis` and have the tunnel set up. (I'm happy to devote a terminal tab to it, although I will try `-N -f` to see if I prefer that.) The host name won't change, and the tunnel needs to go via the bastion. I have tried this:

```
Host redis
    LocalForward 6000 redis.private.foo.com:6379
    ProxyJump bastion
```

This doesn't work, and fails with:

```
channel 0: open failed: connect failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
stdio forwarding failed
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
```

I have no idea why it's complaining about that MAXINT port number…

I don't want to have to duplicate all the `HostName`, `IdentityFile`, etc. for this special case of tunneling to the Redis server. How can I reuse those values but also have a Host configured for when I want the tunnel? [This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1087703/571175) seems to say that I should be able to just add `HostName redis.private.foo.com` to the second Host and it should work, but I get the same error in that case. The only difference is that, with the `HostName` parameter, the connection fails after ~2min instead of 15s.

I have tested and the bastion host is able to connect to the internal host name on the Redis port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to use the `ProxyCommand` option. So I have these two hosts defined in my `~/.ssh/config`:

```ssh-config
Host bastion
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    HostName bastion.foo.com # External bastion hostname
    User my-user
    Port 2222
    PubKeyAuthentication yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bastion.pem
    ServerAliveInterval 30
Host redis
    LocalForward 6000 redis.internal:6379
    Hostname redis.internal # Internal Redis DNS hostname or IP
    ProxyCommand ssh bastion nc %h %p # NB: Connect using above host config
```

When I want to set up the Redis tunnel, I can just use `ssh redis` and it will re-use the config from the bastion host definition.

Answer (score 0):

The important part of that error is `Temporary failure in name resolution`. Your computer is not able to resolve the name `redis.private.foo.com`. Either use the IP or fix the name resolution.  That name must be able to resolved on the bastion. If the bastion can't resolve that name, use the IP.